# How to fix ClientCredential namespace not found

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I get the following error message within visual code even though I've added every reference I can find that's relevant to the issue but I'm still not able to get past the error.  First time using visual code.  What am I missing?

**Offending line**

```
var creds = new ClientCredential(applicationId, clientSecret);  // This line fails to compile
```

**Error received**

> The type or namespace name 'ClientCredential' could not be found

**References added**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="3.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="5.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.ServiceBus" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: did you add "using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;" before the code?

Comment: no #facepalm :-)

Answer (score 0):

Copy Vignesh's comment , it will be helpful to others.

> Just add "using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;" before the code.